# GetOrgChart JSON format

Tags: json, rest, getorgchart

A little startup I am doing work for is searching for a JavaScript Org Chart, and we believe we'd like to use "GetOrgChart" from getorgchart.com.

We definitely have a working back-end already that provides data to the front-end via RESTful services and provides JSON data.

We know the GetOrgChart can be loaded with data from various sources, and in this case we'd like to know what format the JSON has to be in?

Are there any examples out there of how the JSON should look like?

We'd definitely like to download and register this product, but that is one of the questions we'd like to get answered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [their demos page](http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos), you can click the 'Get HTML Code' link (upper right, below the site header) which opens the javascript used to render the demo, including the format of the data.

Comment: Ah, I see it now ... I can see the JSON schema/format.  I presume that I could add more fields to this JSON if I wanted to.  And if I wanted to add more fields to the tree nodes, I presume I would change that somewhere in the GetOrgChart.js?    Thanks for the help!

Comment: Adding more fields is supported, but through custom javascript on your end... they also have an example of that in the demos section.